# Which caches have impact on /UI2/PAGE_BUILDER_PERS?

Tags: sapui5

I have a tile which is missing on the launchpad.

This URL which is called by the Fiori Launchpad to get the different catalogs and groups is producing different data on the backend /IWFND/GW_CLIENT as from the response in the browser:

```
/sap/opu/odata/UI2/PAGE_BUILDER_PERS/PageSets('%2FUI2%2FFiori2LaunchpadHome')?$expand=Pages/PageChipInstances/Chip/ChipBags/ChipProperties,Pages/PageChipInstances/RemoteCatalog,Pages/PageChipInstances/ChipInstanceBags/ChipInstanceProperties,AssignedPages,DefaultPage&sap-cache-id=CE20CFD9090B1ED7AAD26FC5CBBC4A73
```

In the GW client response I can see the Z* catalog and groups which are part of the missing tile, on the response in the browser I cannot and so I know that this is the cause of the missing tile.

Probably a lot of them are unrelated, but these are the reports/tcodes I have executed to clear the caches without having an effect:

- /UI2/CHIP_SYNCHRONIZE_CACHE
- /UI2/DELETE_CACHE
- /UI2/DELETE_CACHE_AFTER_IMP
- /UI2/INVALIDATE_CLIENT_CACHES
- /UI2/INVALIDATE_GLOBAL_CACHES
- /IWFND/CACHE_CLEANUP
- /IWBEP/CACHE_CLEANUP
- SMICM  Menu, Goto -> HTTP Plug-in -> Server Cache -> Invalidate Globally
- /UI2/DELETE_CACHE

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you see the missing data, if you clear your browser cache and use Chrome in incognito mode?

Comment: No, I just tried incognito mode to be sure. But what I always do is open debugger and check "Disable cache" in the network tab.